# How should I power 6 30W (30-36v 1.05A) LEDs from the mains?

Tags: electrical, wiring, led

Was reading about transformers, so basically, which transformer will be optimum, could i get a 36-30v one and not worry about resistors?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure they are 36 (thirty-six) volts, and not 3.6 (three-point-six) volts?

Answer (score 1):

You need more than a "transformer" - you require a DC power supply for most bare LEDs. A transformer is only part of such a supply.

If you are running the LEDs in parallel, resistors are essential - otherwise one unit will end up with "more of the current" and die from it. LEDs are very sensitive to and require precise control of current - the voltage can and does vary. Resistors are a crude way to even this out - and I do mean crude. The resistors and supply voltage need to be chosen so that if an LED is operating at 30V (or 29 if you are the type of pessimist that designs for trouble) it is limited to no more than 1.05 amps; but any LED unit may be operating as high as 36V, and it will not get 1.05 amps with the aforementioned resistor - but you can't "fine tune" the resistors as operating voltage will vary with LED temperature, among other things.

A better (electrically) arrangement is to provide 1.05 (or 1.00-1.04 for some safety factor) amps at 180-216 volts (or 90-108 volts, in two separate supplies, or 60-72 in 3 separate supplies, or 30-36 in 6 separate supplies) with a supply that precisely controls the current and lets the voltage land where it needs to land (variable with temperature, particular individual units of the the LED, etc.) Unsurprisingly, such circuits and the components to build them have become more common as LED lighting has become more common.

If you are electrically/electronically unsophisticated, buying something to suit your needs is more likely to work correctly and cost you less in the long run than building it, unless building it is your route to becoming more sophisticated, and cost is not an object.

(as an aside, the proper thermal design/management is often as much, or more of a challenge in building an effective LED light from bare components as the electrical supply.)